# Ruby catching NameError

Tags: ruby

I have the following code with two classes

```
class DeliveryService
  attr_reader :cities

  def initialize *cities 
    @cities = cities
  end
end

class Product
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end

  def deliver_to delivery_service, city
    if delivery_service.cities.include?(city)
      puts "Product has been delivered"
    else
      puts "Сontact another delivery service"
    end
  end
end
```

I want to `deliver_to` method throw something like "Choose valid delivery service" when invalid `delivery_service` provided (which doesn't exist), but instead I get NameError

I tried to put this in different places in my code

```
rescue NameError
  puts "Choose valid delivery service"
```

but it doesn't work

```
irb(main):001:0> require './DeliveryService.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> fedex = DeliveryService.new "Moscow", "Saint-Petersburg"
=> #<DeliveryService:0x007f66ded31520 @cities=["Moscow", "Saint-Petersburg"]>
irb(main):003:0> product = Product.new "mug"
=> #<Product:0x007f66ded1e498 @name="mug">
irb(main):004:0> product.deliver_to fedex, "Moscow"
Product has been delivered
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> product.deliver_to dhl, "Moscow"
NameError: undefined local variable or method `dhl' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
    from /home/budkin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Dependency Injection on the Correct Object

This is a design problem, in that you aren't getting NameError from within your class; it's being raised when you call `product.deliver_to dhl, "Moscow"` from outside the class. Even if you have a rescue clause as part of your class definition, the NameError is going to be raised *by the caller*.

The right way to fix this is to pass a valid Product object to a valid DeliveryService object instead. A product shouldn't know anything about deliveries anyway; it's a violation of the single responsibility principle. So:

```
class DeliveryService
  def deliver product
  end
end
```

This will give you an instance method that takes a Product, and delivers it through the current delivery service. For example:

```
product = Product.new :widget
dhl = DeliveryService.new 'Moscow'
dhl.deliver product
```

Even if you perform this inversion, you will have problems if you pass invalid objects around, so don't do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

`dh1` does not exist, so you need to wrap your part of the code that attempts to dereference `dh1`.

```
begin
    product.deliver_to dhl, "Moscow" 
rescue NameError => e
    puts e.message
end
```

Although this is quite a messy approach. A better way would be to create an `array` or `set` containing all your companies, and then check if the company is defined in that `set`/`array`.

Comment: I need to `puts` a message for any company that doesn't exist